# Access "create emails" tracking for compiling data

Tags: email, ms-access, tracking

In Access there is a feature called "Create email" whereby you can select a table and send rows to users to fill in data.

When they reply to the email, Access automatically updates with the data they have entered.

Thats great if each user only has one or two rows of data to fill in, but if they need to fill in a large quantity of data, they might only get round to filling in a few records at a time, and potentially not in the same order as is in the database.

How can users keep track of what they have updated and what they havn't?

Does this functionality exist or is this something that Access can't handle?

Many thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

Hardly anything can handle this, because you have no control of what the user may do with your e-mail. Further, you often have to rely on one e-mail client only like Outlook which never will be true in real life where people read mail on all sort of devices.

The best option is to forward a link to a site where the user can input data and where you have full validation of these, and where the collected data are ready for import in your database in a controlled manner.